# How to load a batch of data from json into CoreData entity

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, core-data

I am trying to load some data that I have from a JSON file into a CoreData entity and display it in a View.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the context to save it and/or FetchedRequest to retrieve it. I've debugged it to find that I am making it to `context.save()` but when I go into `FoodSelectionView`, I find that there's no results in `foodItem`. I've attached the code from my `DataController`, `FoodSelectionView` and the app file itself `MacroApp`

`DataController`

```swift
    import Foundation
    import CoreData
    
    class DataController: ObservableObject {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FoodItemsModel")
        
        init() {
            container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Core Data failed to load \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func batchInsertData() {
            let context = container.viewContext
    
            // Insert data as shown in the previous example
            let batchData: [ItemData] = FoodSelectionViewModel().preloadData()
            
            context.perform {
                for item in batchData {
                    let foodItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "FoodItems", into: context) as! FoodItems
                    
                    foodItem.itemName = item.itemName
                    foodItem.id = UUID()
                    foodItem.protein = item.protein
                    foodItem.carbs = item.carbs
                    foodItem.fat = item.fat
                }
                
                do {
                    try context.save()
                    print("Saved")
                } catch {
                    // Handle the error
                    print("Error saving context: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`FoodSelectionView`

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    struct ItemData: Codable {
        let itemName: String
        let fat: Double
        let carbs: Double
        let protein: Double
    }
    
    class FoodSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var foodItemNames: [ItemData] = []
    
        init() {
        }
        
        func preloadData() -> Array<ItemData> {
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foods", withExtension: "json") {
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let itemsArray = try decoder.decode([ItemData].self, from: data)
                    
                    return itemsArray
                } catch {
                    print("Error loading JSON data: \(error)")
                    return []
                }
            }
            print("might be returning zero")
            return []
        }
```

`MacroApp`

```swift
    import SwiftUI
    
    @main
    struct MacroApp: App {
        @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need for `DataController` to be
 `ObservableObject`, you are not publishing anything. Try in your `MacroApp`
 `let dataController = DataController()` (make it a singleton if you need it elsewhere) and
 `@StateObject private var foodModel = FoodSelectionViewModel()` to pass to other views,
using `.environmentObject(foodModel)`.
 
In `func preloadData()` try adding `foodItemNames = itemsArray`
 Have a look at this official link for how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)